# Debugging with CDT + MinGW + Eclipse

Tags: c

I am trying to debug a simple c program using CDT eclipse and MinGW. When I run my program the console shows the desired output. But when I try to debug a program with breakpoints there is no output in the console.. The console is blank..

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you have compiled in debug mode using the `-g` option. If you have done that, maybe the execution is halting at your breakpoint (which is presumably before the code which prints to console). You have to resume execution so that it runs the rest of the code.

Comment: Right-click on Project. Click Properties. Then from C/C++ build options, change the compiler command.